# Maven Project Repository of Jar libraries

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to add Maven to already existing java project. It's been quite an adventure. I've read many questions here but I don't quite get it. The app I'm building is kinda modular so I'm loading many classes from URL so that the need of replacing the .exe (wrapped jar) file is at its minimum (Cuz once opened by any user I'cant update - replace the app (.exe)).

Since I'm using wide variety of libraries and the app Jar, hense the .exe, became too large - ~80MB, and slow to open from fileshare. Hense the need of Maven (or so I think). Since I installed Maven I had to add package statement at the top of every class, because before then there was not such thing, nor the need for it. Maven found the dependencies online and for the most part the process was not so time consuming, but the goal is to load the libraries from the project(app) folder /lib/. There I have all the libraries in jar files that I need. My question is: Is there a need of installing the libraries to local m2 directory (as I've read) since the app should always load them from the app folder? How do I configure the POM so the project/lib/ directory is recognized as a repo (or even is this the right approach), and load the libraries from the relative path of the project folder?
Thanks in advance to anyone able and willing to help!

Answer (score 1):

Maven's core objective is to manage dependencies. You can add a dependency to your project, by configuring it in pom.xml, maven will download the dependency from the maven central repository & when building the project, maven can help you create a runnable JAR that have all your dependencies & code compiled.

Let's say in your current project if all of the dependencies are absolutely necessary, then even after migrating the project to maven, you're runnable JAR will remain the same size. There won't be any reduction in your application size. However, I would highly recommend migrating your project to any build tool like gradle or maven to manage project dependencies.

Comment: So, there is no way to load the libraries in runtime or make connections from the app itself?

Comment: And could you suggest a way in which that could happen? Regards, Peter

Comment: I am wondering why you're not sharing one runnable JAR that have all your code & dependencies.

Comment: As I've mentioned in the question the Jar is way to big - around 80MB, ,so when I try to run the app from the network location that is in, it takes too much time to load. I don't think that there is not a solution as many java apps use external libraries which are not packed in the jar, and next in the wrapped jar (a.k.a the .exe file). :)

Comment: Maybe you can break down your app into different components & when running the app, start loading only the most essential component so that your app will boot quickly & in the background keep on loading each component as needed or preemptively. You don't need to download & run the code on the fly.